# Error while updating. 'attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

HI

I am using sqlite database. I know after application crash or system crash database get locked..

How I avoid to get my sqlite db locked.

How does I check that database lock during DML queries.

How does I open locked database.

Thanks

Mandeep

following is My Code.

```
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
    return defaultDBPath;
```

Now I changed above code to this.

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Many examples of using SQLite in Cocoa apps mention the approach of storing an empty "template" database copy as a resource within the application bundle. It's important to note an app bundle is not supposed to be writable, so this approach requires you copy the template to a writable location (use the standard storage locations, please) and use *that* file as your writable copy.

Could this be your problem?

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi, yes think.
I am getting following crash log.
**Error while updating. 'attempt to write a readonly database'
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/MyApp.sqlite
Assertion failure in +[Database insertRecord:Name:Assignment:], /Users/Deep/Desktop/MyApp/Database.m:327**

Comment: Looks like the problem to me. You need to copy your template database file to a normal file location (like ~/Library/Application Support/My Company/MyApp/MyApp.sqlite) if it's not present and use THAT.

Comment: Where's your attempt to copy the default database from the bundle to the documents dir if it doesn't exist in the documents dir when requested?

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi, yes I am now doing this.

Comment: Clearly there's somewhere you're still accessing the database in the bundle's resources. You'll need to find out where and knock it off. :-)